# htaccess Redirect to same file, but display different URL without having to change internal links?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have links on my website in the form of:- `http://example.com/products.php?cat=X`

I want that once taken to the destination of the link, the url displays something like:- `http://example.com/new`.

The file on my server is the same file, but only the url should appear neater without me having to change any of the links.

I tried the following, but found it only useful if I explicitly changed the internal links:-

`RewriteRule ^new$ products.php?cat=10`

Comment: Do you mean when you hover over a link it is showing products.php?cat=10  ?  If thats the case, yes you need to change your links to /new

Comment: I mainly want that the destination of the page is not products.php?cat=10 but instead /new, where the contents of /new are exactly the same and without me having to create a new file.  It would also be nice but not essential that when hovering over the links, it does not display products.php?cat=10.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =cat=10
RewriteRule ^products.php$ new [R,L]

RewriteRule ^new$ products.php?cat=10 [L]
```

Comment: I tried this but I would still have to change the link address inside my php files in order to take me to http://example.com/new.  I want a solution where I would not have to change the internal links.

Comment: The first rule rewrites `products.php?cat=10` to `new` in the browser, and the second rule rewrites `new` to `products.php?cat=10` internally in httpd.

Comment: The thing is that even after entering these in my .htaccess, when I click on a link to products.php?cat=10, I am not taken to /new.

Comment: My apologies, I had a typo in RewriteCond. Fixed now.

Comment: I tried this and I got ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Answer (score 0):

Check the original requested URL in the [request line](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET /products\.php\?([^&]*&+)*cat=X
RewriteRule ^products\.php$ /new? [L,R=301]
```

But it will probably be easier if you do that with PHP (see `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`).